# MacBook Pro Retina late-2013 WiFi BC4360 - "FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY"

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom, macbook-pro

I've just booted Ubuntu 15.10 from USB dongle on my MacBook Pro Retina late-2013 and WiFi networking doesn't work. I can see the following output in DMESG and LSPCI

```
[   19.556114] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   19.556117] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   19.556117] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   19.556119] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.556120] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.556121] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.556122] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.556123] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   19.556124] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   19.556125] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.556125] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
[   19.594061] b43-phy0: Broadcom 4360 WLAN found (core revision 42)
[   19.594524] b43-phy0 ERROR: FOUND UNSUPPORTED PHY (Analog 12, Type 11 (AC), Revision 1)

$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
   description: Network controller
   product: BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
   resources: irq:18 memory:c1a00000-c1a07fff memory:c1800000-c19fffff

LSPCI output:
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
```

Furthermore, my mac freezed up after very few time, after opening the top left menu with apps, maybe something related to graphics because previously it got frozen also after trying to change resolution.

Answer (score 2):

It is telling you that b43, ssb and its firmware are incorrect for your device. With a working, reliable internet connection, ideally ethernet, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working correctly.